# How do I decompress the diagram data in a .drawio file with node.js and zlib?

Tags: node.js, zlib, draw.io

[Diagrams.net](https://www.diagrams.net/), previously and still more widely known as draw.io, is a popular tool for drawing diagrams of various kinds. It stores diagrams in an XML-based format that uses the file ending .drawio. The file content has the structure:

```
<mxfile {...}>
  <diagram {...}>
    {the-actual-diagram-content}
  </diagram>
</mxfile>`
```

According to the documentation page [*Extracting the XML from mxfiles*](https://drawio-app.com/extracting-the-xml-from-mxfiles/), the string `{the-actual-diagram-content}` contains the actual diagram data in compressed format, "compressed with the standard deflate process". I'd like to decompress this data in my node.js app to parse and modify it.

I have found an [older, similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630478/uncompressing-drawio-file-in-node-js), which wants the same, but uses the libraries "atob", and later "pako". I'd like to achieve the same with the more standard "zlib" node.js module, which - if this is really "the standard deflate process" - should be possible.

However, all my attempts to "inflate" the compressed string fail. I have mostly tried variations of the following code, with different encodings ('base64', 'utf8') and methods ('inflateSync', 'unzipSync', 'gunzipSync'):

```
zlib.inflateSync(Buffer.from(string, 'base64')).toString();
```

All attempts fail with the error "Error: incorrect header check". I read this as "dude, seriously, you're using the wrong unzip algorithm for this". However, I cannot figure out what the right algorithm or settings are.

The sample string I'd like to decode is the following. Using the [jgraph inflate/deflate tool](https://jgraph.github.io/drawio-tools/tools/convert.html), this uncompresses perfectly fine. However, the settings done there, "URL Encode", "Deflate", "Base64" sound to me exactly like what I am trying.

```
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
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's strictly encodeURIComponent, which is a minor variation of URL encode, https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-tools/blob/master/tools/convert.html#L69. I think zlib has inflateRaw() / deflateRaw() functions, if yes, I would try those.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zlib.inflateRawSync()`. What you have there is a raw deflate stream, not a zlib stream.